# Azure DocumentDB, When uploading af executing - no result?

Tags: azure, webrequest, azure-cosmosdb

In my project I am supposed to get data from openweathermap.org and put that in a collection in my DocumentDB database in Azure.

The code below works locally on my development machine, but when i upload the project, it runs and succeed (says the dashboard) but no documents are created. I can only create the documents if I run from local machine.

Why is that?

Here is my code:

```
public static void Main()
    {


        JobHost host = new JobHost();
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("saveWeatherDataToAzureDocumentDB"));

    }

    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static async void saveWeatherDataToAzureDocumentDB()
    {
        string endpointUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndPointUrl"];
        string authorizationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizationKey"];

        string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=hanstholm,dk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98";


        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        string text;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }


        // Create a new instance of the DocumentClient
        var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);

        // Check to verify a database with the id=FamilyRegistry does not exist
        Database database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(db => db.Id == "weatherdata").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
        // If the database does not exist, create a new database
        if (database == null)
        {
            database = await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(
                new Database
                {
                    Id = "weatherdata"
                });
        }

        // Check to verify a document collection with the id=FamilyCollection does not exist
        DocumentCollection documentCollection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(database.SelfLink).Where(c => c.Id == "weathercollection").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

        // If the document collection does not exist, create a new collection
        if (documentCollection == null)
        {
            documentCollection = await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync("dbs/" + database.Id,
                new DocumentCollection
                {
                    Id = "weathercollection"
                });
        }

        //Deserialiser til et dynamisk object
        if (text == "")
        {
            mark m = new mark() { name = "Something" };

            await client.CreateDocumentAsync(documentCollection.DocumentsLink, m);

        }
        else
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(text);
            json["id"] = json["name"] + "_" + DateTime.Now;
            await client.CreateDocumentAsync(documentCollection.DocumentsLink, json);
        }

    }
    public sealed class mark
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

---

UPDATE - This is what I have in my App.config

```
<appSettings>
<!-- Replace the value with the value you copied from the Azure management portal -->
<add key="EndPointUrl" value="https://<My account>.documents.azure.com:443/"/>
<!-- Replace the value with the value you copied from the Azure management portal -->
<add key="AuthorizationKey" value="The secret code from Azure"/>
```

Also, At DocumentDB Account i find the Connection string like this. AccountEndpoint=https://knoerregaard.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=my secret password 
How should I apply this to the WebJob?

Appriciate your help!

Comment: Have you confirmed that your web job is getting its app configuration settings correctly (e.g. from the web app settings)?

Comment: No i dont think so. How to do that?

Comment: You are reading from `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]` - if you don't have anything in your app.config or in your `Application Settings`, these won't have any values, so you won't be able to connect to DocumentDB. I really don't know what the issue is, but I'm just offering some basic thing to check, since reading your docdb url and key is the only config-based operation you're doing.

Comment: Please see update. I have the two values from DocumentDB Account on Azure.

Comment: I guess it is something to do with the Webjob. What should go into Connection String on the WebJob.

Comment: silly question, are you sure your web job is being triggered and actually runs?